# "cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated" what does this means and how to repair it?

Tags: btrfs

I'm having a little problem trying to grow a btrfs partition in my system, namely:

```
sudo btrfsck /dev/sdb9 
[sudo] password for braiam: 
Checking filesystem on /dev/sdb9
UUID: f7e9ac38-5068-4c55-97ab-41430b360d4f
checking extents
checking free space cache
cache and super generation don't match, space cache will be invalidated
checking fs roots
checking csums
There are no extents for csum range 0-69632
Csum exists for 0-69632 but there is no extent record
found 10204750230 bytes used err is 1
total csum bytes: 10835824
total tree bytes: 80138240
total fs tree bytes: 59863040
total extent tree bytes: 4743168
btree space waste bytes: 21830024
file data blocks allocated: 11097911296
 referenced 11097911296
Btrfs v3.16
```

and I'm trying to fix it. Sadly, the patch that added that check (btw, if it fails it will return a exit code 1) doesn't explain what it is, nor how can we fix it. Now, the partition works seven wonders, but I cannot resize it. Is there a way that I can fix this issue and prevent it from occurring again in the future?

Answer (score 4):

There's a post on the [btrfs list](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg61708.html) that suggests using the `--clear-space-cache` option. The following command fixed the same problem for me:

`btrfs check --clear-space-cache v1 /dev/sda5`